# a simple indexed join on two tables taking ages

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to do the following select:

```
select `table1`.`index2`
    from `table1`, `table2`
    where `table1`.`index1` = `table2`.`index1`
        and `table1`.`index2` != `table2`.`index2`
```

`index1` and `index2` are `varchar(255)` and are indexed. both tables contain about 50k rows.
This query took 10 mins and I killed it because its way too long.
Why is it taking so long?

Comment: are all four `table1`.`index1`, `table2`.`index1`, `table1`.`index2` and `table2`.`index2` indexed? Just to make sure ...

Comment: Why don't you use left join or inner join ?

Comment: @cularis, yes they are indexed

Comment: @Jerome C., its an inner join already, just implicit syntax

Comment: Please post the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Is this query has best performance ? Using left outer join or inner join sometimes improve the query.

```
select `table1`.`index2`
from `table1`
inner join table2 on `table1`.`index1` = `table2`.`index1`
    and `table1`.`index2` != `table2`.`index2`
```

Comment: this is already inner join with implicit syntax.... you query is identical to mine

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, has nothing to do with the query.
Look like creating the index like

```
index(`index1`, `index2`)
```

creates some sort of stupid index, but creating it like

```
index(`index1`),
index(`index2`)
```

fixed my problems. what is the first one doing?